# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please help me with the issue . I have tried lot many solution and they are not working .

```
rd["DOB"].ToString() = "9/19/1946";

 DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(rd["DOB"].ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use "M/d/yyyy" as the format string.

MM/dd/yyyy would match 09/19/1946, but not 9/19/1946

Answer (score 2):

You can refer below URL for more grasp on date time format
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the Convert class?

```
Convert.ToDateTime(rd["DOB"]);
```

If you are using System.Data.DataRow and the column "DOB" is of type SqlDateTime then that should work.